# C# location of file

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, c#-3.0

In a C# 2008 windows application, I planning on locating files that I need to find by utilizing the following code:

```
    var RFiles = from path in Directory.EnumerateFiles(filesaveLocation, "*.*", 
     SearchOption.AllDirectories) 
     let extension = Path.GetExtension(path) 
      where extension == ".pdf" || extension == ".xlsx" || extension == ".xls" 
      select path;
```

However once I find each selected file, I need to know the exact location of where each specified file was located. I need to be able to store the exact directory structure location in a sql server 2008 r2 database.

Basically the code statement would be similar to tell me exactly where each selected file  is located at.

Thus can you me in code and/or explain to me how to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 1):

`Directory.EnumerateFiles` returns full file paths, location + filename. Just print it or check in debug mode.